# Using a custom docker with Azure ML

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm following the guidelines (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-environments) to use a custom docker file on Azure. My script to create the environment looks like this:

```
from azureml.core.environment import Environment

myenv = Environment(name = "myenv")
myenv.docker.enabled = True
dockerfile = r"""
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/base:intelmpi2018.3-ubuntu16.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libgl1-mesa-glx
RUN echo "Hello from custom container!"
"""
myenv.docker.base_image = None
myenv.docker.base_dockerfile = dockerfile
```

Upon execution, this is totally ignored and libgl1 is not installed. Any ideas why?

EDIT: Here's the rest of my code:

```
est = Estimator(
    source_directory = '.',
    script_params = script_params,
    use_gpu = True,
    compute_target = 'gpu-cluster-1',
    pip_packages = ['scipy==1.1.0', 'torch==1.5.1'],
    entry_script = 'AzureEntry.py',
    )

run = exp.submit(config = est)
run.wait_for_completion(show_output=True)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-environments

Comment: can you share a bit more of your code? How the environment is used, in particular? scoring? training?

Comment: Added some details. It is being used for training.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work :

```
from azureml.core import Workspace
from azureml.core.environment import Environment
from azureml.train.estimator import Estimator
from azureml.core.conda_dependencies import CondaDependencies
from azureml.core import Experiment

ws = Workspace (...)
exp = Experiment(ws, 'test-so-exp')

myenv = Environment(name = "myenv")
myenv.docker.enabled = True
dockerfile = r"""
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/base:intelmpi2018.3-ubuntu16.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libgl1-mesa-glx
RUN echo "Hello from custom container!"
"""
myenv.docker.base_image = None
myenv.docker.base_dockerfile = dockerfile

## You need to instead put your packages in the Environment definition instead... 
## see below for some changes too

myenv.python.conda_dependencies = CondaDependencies.create(pip_packages = ['scipy==1.1.0', 'torch==1.5.1'])
```

Finally you can build your estimator a bit differently :

```
est = Estimator(
    source_directory = '.',
#     script_params = script_params,
#     use_gpu = True,
    compute_target = 'gpu-cluster-1',
#     pip_packages = ['scipy==1.1.0', 'torch==1.5.1'],
    entry_script = 'AzureEntry.py',
    environment_definition=myenv
    )
```

And submit it :

```
run = exp.submit(config = est)
run.wait_for_completion(show_output=True)
```

Let us know if that works.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Works perfectly :)

Answer (score 4):

Have no issues installing the lib. First, please dump your dockerfile content into a file, easier to maintain and read ;)

```
e = Environment("custom")
e.docker.base_dockerfile = "path/to/your/dockerfile"
```

will set the content of the file into a string prop.

```
e.register(ws).build(ws).wait_for_completion()
```

step 2/16 will have your apt update and libgl1 install

Note, that should work with >=1.7 SDK

Comment: When I try this I get:
Image Build Status: Running,
Image Build Status: Failed

Comment: FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/intelmpi2018.3-ubuntu16.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libgl1-mesa-glx


is the content of the dockerfile I have. What's your azureml-core version?

Comment: This builds correctly, but unfortunately my experiment still fails (libGL not found). I think the issue is that the environment is not being used within the experiment...

Comment: as Larry mentioned, you need to set environment object in the estimator. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-train-core/azureml.train.estimator.estimator?view=azure-ml-py. environment_definition parameter, please move python dependencies from pip packages into environment object to have one source of truth

Comment: This works great now. Thanks very much. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Totally understandable why you're struggling -- [others have also expressed a need for more information](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/issues/875).

1. perhaps `base_dockerfile` needs to be a text file (with the contents inside) and not a string? I'll  ask the environments PM to learn more specifically how this works
2. another  option would be to lever Azure Container Instance (ACI). An ACI is created automatically when spinning up an Azure ML workspace. See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/issues/1049) for more info on that.

Answer (score 1):

For more information about using Docker in environments, see the article `Enable
Docker https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-environments#enable-docker
The following example shows how to load docker steps as a string.

```
   from azureml.core import Environment
   myenv = Environment(name="myenv")

   # Creates the environment inside a Docker container.
   myenv.docker.enabled = True

   # Specify docker steps as a string.
   dockerfile = r'''
   FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/intelmpi2018.3-ubuntu16.04
   RUN echo "Hello from custom container!"
   '''

   # Alternatively, load from a file.
   #with open("dockerfiles/Dockerfile", "r") as f:
   #    dockerfile=f.read()

   myenv.docker.base_dockerfile = dockerfile
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work -- you can plainly see that my example is consistent with this, and it does not produce desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's that you're using an estimator. Estimators create their own environment, unless you set the `environment_definition` parameter, which I don't see in your snippet. I'm looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-train-core/azureml.train.estimator.estimator?view=azure-ml-py.

Haven't tried it, but I think you can fix this by changing your code to:

```
est = Estimator(
    source_directory = '.',
    script_params = script_params,
    use_gpu = True,
    compute_target = 'gpu-cluster-1',
    pip_packages = ['scipy==1.1.0', 'torch==1.5.1'],
    entry_script = 'AzureEntry.py',
    environment_definition = myenv
    )

run = exp.submit(config = est)
run.wait_for_completion(show_output=True)
```

You might also have to move `use_gpu` setting into the environment definition, as the SDK page I linked above says that the environment will take precedence over this and a couple other estimator parameters.

Comment: This was indeed part of the problem!! For other readers: when specifying a custom environment (environment_definition = myenv), the pip_packages as specified in the Estimator initialization are ignored. You'll need to add them to the custom environment, e.g. myenv.python.conda_dependencies = conda_dep